# Spark TaskNotSerializable when using anonymous function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, closures, serializable

**Background**

Here's my situation: I'm trying to create a class that filters an RDD based on some feature of the contents, but that feature can be different in different scenarios so I'd like to parameterize that with a function. Unfortunately, I seem to be running into issues with the way Scala captures its closures. Even though my function is serializable, the class is not.

From the example in the [spark source on closure cleaning](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/c1bc4f439f54625c01a585691e5293cd9961eb0c/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/ClosureCleaner.scala#L148), it seems to suggest my situation can't be solved, but I'm convinced there's a way to achieve what I'm trying to do by creating the right (smaller) closure.

**My Code**

```
class MyFilter(getFeature: Element => String, other: NonSerializable) {
  def filter(rdd: RDD[Element]): RDD[Element] = {
    // All my complicated logic I want to share
    rdd.filter { elem => getFeature(elem) == "myTargetString" }     
}
```

**Simplified Example**

```
class Foo(f: Int => Double, rdd: RDD[Int]) { 
  def go(data: RDD[Int]) = data.map(f) 
}

val works = new Foo(_.toDouble, otherRdd)
works.go(myRdd).collect() // works

val myMap = Map(1 -> 10d)
val complicatedButSerializableFunc: Int => Double = x => myMap.getOrElse(x, 0)
val doesntWork = new Foo(complicatedButSerializableFunc, otherRdd)
doesntWork.go(myRdd).collect() // craps out

org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: $iwC$$iwC$Foo
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: $iwC$$iwC$Foo, value: $iwC$$iwC$Foo@61e33118)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: foo, type: class $iwC$$iwC$Foo)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@47d6a31a)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1, name: $outer, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1, <function1>)

// Even though
val out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("test.obj"))
out.writeObject(complicatedButSerializableFunc) // works
```

**Questions**

1. Why does the first simplied example not attempt to serialize all of `Foo` but the second one does?
2. How can I get the reference to my serializable function without including a reference to `Foo` in my closure?

Comment: Are you using the spark-shell to test your code or is it within an spark application?

Comment: @eliasah this is within the spark-shell

Comment: and what about your spark version?

Comment: Fails in 1.2, 1.4, and 1.5 for me.

Comment: Ok. I suggest that you try your code inside a spark application. I seems like a bug in the REPL

Comment: Why do you pass `myRdd` twice? Once when you create an instance of `Foo`, and then again when you call the `go()` method on your instance? It's not obvious to me this is necessary -- to me it looks like you only need to pass it when you call `go()`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @DMH that was a toy example, realistically they were 2 different RDDs. You can replace the RDD passed in through the constructor with anything that is not serializable to reproduce the error.

Comment: Ok, got it, thanks. The same thing is in `Foo` in your solution below, so I wanted to make sure I wasn't misunderstanding what you did. Thanks again.

Comment: Sure thing glad it helped. Edited to eliminate confusion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the answer with the help of [this article](http://erikerlandson.github.io/blog/2015/03/31/hygienic-closures-for-scala-function-serialization/).

Essentially, when creating the closure for a given function, Scala will include the entire object for any complex field referenced (if someone has a good explanation for why this doesn't happen in the first simple example, I'll accept that answer). The solution is to pass the serializable value to a different function so that only the minimal reference is kept, very similar to the ol' javascript for-loop paradigm for event listeners.

**Example**

```
def enclose[E, R](enclosed: E)(func: E => R): R = func(enclosed)

class Foo(f: Int => Double, somethingNonserializable: RDD[String]) { 
 def go(data: RDD[Int]) = enclose(f) { actualFunction => data.map(actualFunction) } 
}
```

**Or with JS-style self-executing anonymous function**

```
def go(data: RDD[Int]) = ((actualFunction: Int => Double) => data.map(actualFunction))(f)
```